# How to https request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

When I request with Node.js I got 0 error though I still get a problem :
with my code, I wanna register to a website with a request and when I try to log in with information seems like it doesn't register, so yeah I wanna know if someone knows what I do wrong or just I can't do https request or have not to access to do it. However, thank for taking the time to read my question.

Here's my code:

```js
let request = require('request');

let url = 'https://gamehag.com/api/v1/register';

let headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
};

let pseudo = 'test1236';

let formData = {
    name: pseudo,
    email: `${pseudo}@gmail.com`,
    password: pseudo,
    geo: 'pl'
};

request.post({ url: url, form: formData, headers: headers, method: 'POST'}, (err, res, body) => {
    console.log('HEADERS');
    console.log('----------------------');
    console.log(res.headers)
    console.log('----------------------');
    console.log('BODY');
    console.log('----------------------');
    console.log(body)
    console.log('----------------------');
});
```

And what it outputs in the cmd:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj7JQ.png)

Comment: what errors are you receiving?

Comment: i don't receive any error. My code is trying to register with pseudo and password : test1236 on the website: gamehag.com. So the problem, is normally if i try to connect on the webiste with test1236 as pseudo and test1236 as password i should log in but seems like the request didn't worked... why idk i want to solve that problem ^^

Comment: "it seems like the request didn't worked" -- what do you mean by this? how didn't it work? "idk i want to solve that problem" -- what is the problem that you ran into? you need to be more specific to have people help you out. This is a very vague question.

Comment: ehhh, how to say check out this first: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj7JQ.png, and then what i can tell you is that i didn't receive any error like in node.js but i'm not sure i'm not very "pro" at node.js but i think i can't do it from Node.js maybe (the request) ?? Cause check out the image link i sent you i show you what it outputs the body and response headers from the request and normally i can login  ^^ so idk how to help you guys to solve my problem. Otherwise, thanks for answer ;)

Comment: Can you post the link to the API `https://gamehag.com/api/v1/register` that you are calling?

Comment: i don't get what you mean

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

You're missing the `x-csrf-token` header for cloudflare.

```
let request = require('request');

let url = 'https://gamehag.com/api/v1/register';

let csrfToken = getToken("https://gamehag.com"); 
//return document.head.getElementsByTagName('meta')[2].content;

let headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'x-csrf-token': csrfToken
};
```

Comment: what are the follow redirect please ?

Comment: I see, sorry I didn't really see what you were doing. Okay I'll update my answer

Comment: Ah ok thank you but i got the error "getToken is not defined" ??

Comment: Up. Man the getToken() function doesn't exist please help me ;)

Comment: Adam, before going directly to the post you'll need to do the following:
1 Go to the main page via GET 
2. From there pull the CSRF code using parsing. 
3. Now you're ready to make the `register` POST

Comment: Up one more time. Help please, Proximo could you code it cause seems like it doesn't work for me you're better so please ;)

Comment: proximo help me ;)